# How to ignore .php, .csv, .randomstring, etc. in URL using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php script that minifies my css and spits it out with this url:

```
domain.com/resource.php?resource=css_file.css
```

However it doesn't show anything. If I remove the .css at the end of the url then it shows the minified css code.

This resource manager manages tons of file types so how do I get htaccess ignore ALL endings(.php, .css, .js etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without using url_rewrite, add this on top of your resource.php :

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET['resource'])) {
  if (strpos($_GET['resource'], '.') !== false) {
     header('Location: resource.php?resource='.preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename));  
  }
}
```